# How to position tables in overlap?

Tags: tables, minipage, geometry

I look forward to creating the following illustration:

[image]

My code:

```latex
%%% code replaced in the edit.
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer from @JohnKormylo, I modified my code as below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{physics} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, node distance=1.cm]

    % Row 1
    \node (A) {
      \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{m-1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{m}} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        0 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
        1 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
        . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
        . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
        \textit{n-1} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
        \textit{n} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \node[right=of A] (B) {
      \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{m-1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{m}} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        0 &  & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor{gray!10} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        1 & \cellcolor{gray!40} & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
        . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!75} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        . & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        \textit{n-1} & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\
        \cline{2-6}
        \textit{n} &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \\
        \cline{2-6}
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \node[right=of B] (C) {
      \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{m}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{..}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{m-1}} \\
        \cline{2-6}
         & \cellcolor{gray!100} & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!50} } &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  \cellcolor{gray!25} } & \cellcolor{gray!10} \\
        \cline{2-6}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   \multicolumn{4}{l}{ $ \underbrace{ \text{. . . . . . . . . . . } }_\textit{ Subspace } $ }      &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
      \end{tabular}
    };

    %%% Row 2  %%%
    \node [below=of A] (D){
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m-1} }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
    0 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n-1} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}  
    };

     \node[right=of D](E){
     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m-1} }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
    0 & \cellcolor{gray!100} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ ..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!75}} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ ..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!50}} & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!75} } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . & \cellcolor{gray!100} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!75} } & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n-1} & \cellcolor{gray!75}  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n} & \cellcolor{gray!50} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!75} } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}
     };

     \node[right=of E](F){
     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m-1 } } & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{..}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
     & \cellcolor{gray!100} & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!50} } &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  \cellcolor{gray!50} } & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   \multicolumn{4}{l}{ $ \underbrace{ \text{. . . . . . . . . . . } }_\textit{ Subspace } $ }      &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    \end{tabular}
     };

     %%% Row 3 %%%%
     \node[below=of D](G){
     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m-1} }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
    0 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n-1} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}
     };

     \node[right=of G](H){
     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ ..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m-1} }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m} } \\
    \cline{2-6}
    0 & \cellcolor{gray!100}  & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . & \cellcolor{gray!100} &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n-1} & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n} & \cellcolor{gray!50}  & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}
     };

     \node[right=of H](I){
     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ 1 } } & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m-1 } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
     & \cellcolor{gray!100} & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!50} } &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  \cellcolor{gray!25} } &  \cellcolor{gray!10} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &   \multicolumn{4}{l}{ $ \underbrace{ \text{. . . . . . . . . . . } }_\textit{ Subspace } $ }      &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    \end{tabular}
     };

     % Captions
    \node[above=0cm of A] {$ \phi_1(x_{i,j})$};
    \node[above=0cm of B] {$ | \phi_1(x_{i,j}) | $};
    \node[above=0cm of C] {$ \vb{x}_1   = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\phi(x_{i,j})| $};

    \node[above=0cm of D] {$ \phi_2(x_{i,j})$};
    \node[above=0cm of E] {$ | \phi_2(x_{i,j}) | $};
    \node[above=0cm of F] {$ \vb{x}_2   = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\phi(x_{i,j})| $};

    \node[above=0cm of G] {$ \phi_k(x_{i,j})$};
    \node[above=0.cm of H] {$ | \phi_k(x_{i,j}) | $};
    \node[above=0.cm of I] {$ \vb{x}_k   = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\phi(x_{i,j})| $};
    
    % Below
    \node[below=0.1cm of G]{First phase};
    \node[below=0.1cm of H]{Second phase};
    \node[below=0.1cm of I]{Third phase};

     % Arrows for row 1
    \draw [->] (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C);
    \draw [->] (D) edge (E) (E) edge (F);
    \draw [->] (G) edge (H) (H) edge (I);
     
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Process description here.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To produce:

[image]

**Question**

How do I modify this to:

- make tables overlap
- accordingly, adjust the captions to the sides of the nodes?

Comment: Can you provide a more descriptive title to your question? This would help those that do searches and only see post snippets. Ask "How can I do *this*?" doesn't help in that regard.

Comment: The three illustrations total 0.9\textwidth, which doesn't leave much room for arrows.  In any case, to position, overlap and make opaque (fill=white) I would put each illustration into a tikz node and do the whole thing as a tikspicture.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you add some details to your comment (or an answer)?

Comment: single-column `\multicolumn` commands such as `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{..}` are often not necessary. I would check whether you can remove them (if you want to stick to the `tabular` approach).

Comment: Scaling the picture to the width of the text body seems not to be the best approach, I fear, as you need to approximately halve the width. Maybe you can rearrange things, for example from top to bottom instead of horinzontally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Ti*k*Z matrices instead of tabulars which would make positioning easy and also solve the problem with cell coloring. Since you use the same matrix several times, you could make a `\pic` from it to simplify the code (which is still quite lengthy). In the following example, I did not color the cells correctly since I only wanted to show you the basic approach:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    tabular matrix/.style={
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            font=\footnotesize,
            minimum width=2.75em, 
            minimum height=1.5em,
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=center,
            execute at end node=\strut,
            draw,
            fill=white
        },
        row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                draw=none
            }
        },
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={
                draw=none
            }
        },
    },
    pics/tabular/.style={
        code={
            \matrix[tabular matrix, ampersand replacement=\&, #1] (-m) { 
                   \& 0 \& 1 \& \cdots \& m-1 \& m \\
                 0 \&   \&   \& \cdots \&   \&   \\
                 1 \&   \&   \& \cdots \&   \&   \\
                 \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \\
                 \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \& \cdot \\
                 n-1 \&   \&   \& \cdots \&   \&   \\
                 n \&   \&   \& \cdots \&   \&   \\
            };
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \pic (a-\i) at ({\i*1.25},{\i*-2.5}) {tabular};
    \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]a-\i-m.west) {$\varphi_{
        \ifnum\i=3\relax k\else3\fi
    }(x_{i,j})$};
}

\pic at ([xshift=6cm]a-1-m.east) (b-1) {tabular={
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!75}},
    row 3 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!40}},
    row 4 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!25}}
}};
\draw[-stealth] (a-1-m.east) -- (b-1-m.west);
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]b-1-m.west) 
    {$|\varphi_{1}(x_{i,j})|$};

\pic at ([xshift=6cm]a-2-m.east) (b-2) {tabular={
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!75}},
    row 3 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!40}},
    row 4 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!25}}
}};
\draw[-stealth] (a-2-m.east) -- (b-2-m.west);
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]b-2-m.west) 
    {$|\varphi_{2}(x_{i,j})|$};

\pic at ([xshift=6cm]a-3-m.east) (b-3) {tabular={
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!75}},
    row 3 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!40}},
    row 4 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!25}}
}};
\draw[-stealth] (a-3-m.east) -- (b-3-m.west);
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-0.5cm]b-3-m.west) 
    {$|\varphi_{k}(x_{i,j})|$};

\matrix[tabular matrix, column 1/.style={nodes=draw},
    row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!75}},
    row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray!40}},
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!25}}
] (c-1-m) at ([shift={(6cm, 0.75em)}]b-1-m.east) { 
   1 & m & 0 &   & \cdots & m-1 \\
     &   &   &   &   &   \\
};
\draw[decorate, decoration=brace] 
    ([yshift=-2pt]c-1-m-2-5.south east) -- ([yshift=-2pt]c-1-m-2-1.south west) 
    node[below, midway] {subspace};

\draw[-stealth] (b-1-m.east) -- (b-1-m.east -| c-1-m.west);
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=0.25cm]c-1-m.north) 
    {$x_{1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\varphi_{1}(x_{i,j})| \geq \rho$};

\matrix[tabular matrix, column 1/.style={nodes=draw},
    row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!75}},
    row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray!40}},
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!25}}
] (c-2-m) at ([shift={(6cm, 0.75em)}]b-2-m.east) { 
   0 & m-1 & 1 &   & \cdots & m \\
     &   &   &   &   &   \\
};
\draw[decorate, decoration=brace] 
    ([yshift=-2pt]c-2-m-2-4.south east) -- ([yshift=-2pt]c-2-m-2-1.south west) 
    node[below, midway] {subspace};

\draw[-stealth] (b-2-m.east) -- (b-2-m.east -| c-2-m.west);
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=0.25cm]c-2-m.north) 
    {$x_{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\varphi_{2}(x_{i,j})| \geq \rho$};

\matrix[tabular matrix, column 1/.style={nodes=draw},
    row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!75}},
    row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=gray!40}},
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=gray!25}}
] (c-3-m) at ([shift={(6cm, 0.75em)}]b-3-m.east) { 
   0 & 1 & m &   & \cdots & m-1 \\
     &   &   &   &   &   \\
};
\draw[decorate, decoration=brace] 
    ([yshift=-2pt]c-3-m-2-5.south east) -- ([yshift=-2pt]c-3-m-2-1.south west) 
    node[below, midway] {subspace};

\draw[-stealth] (b-3-m.east) -- (b-3-m.east -| c-3-m.west);
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=0.25cm]c-3-m.north) 
    {$x_{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\varphi_{k}(x_{i,j})| \geq \rho$};


\node at (0,-10 -| a-1-m) {a.) First phase};
\node at (0,-10 -| b-1-m) {b.) Second phase};
\node at (0,-10 -| c-1-m) {c.) Third phase};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure! I so much like this answer. You make my day!

Comment: @arilwan I just updated the answer a bit to make the output a bit less wide. You may want to shift around the nodes and things to your liking.

Comment: Trying to figure out what changes to make to fit in the template I am using, as in the edit. Any pointer to that?

Comment: @arilwan If you need to scale the output, you could decrease the font size (especially in the matrices) using `\tiny`. You can also, of course, reduce certain lengths in the code manually (e.g. of the arrows). And you could also scale the whole `tikzpicture` using the `scale` (or just the `xscale`) option. The `scale` option would not affect the text or the line widths, so I am unsure whether the output would look that nice. Finally, as a kind of sledgehammer approach, you can scale the `tikzpicture` including the font and the line widths by adding `transform canvas` to the `scale`  option.

Comment: A workaround is to to use this exactly as it is in a separate file, download the pdf and insert as image in my main work. Until this answer, I thought I know much about LaTeX, learned alot from it.

Answer (score 1):

This should get your started using a tikzpicture.  However, colored tabulars are not my area of expertise, except I know that missing lines are common using xcolor.  There are packages like tabulararray which specialize in this, but you will probably have to use a savebox since you cannot put a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{Illustration}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt, fill=white, font=\small}]
\node(A) {%
   \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0 } &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ .. } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m-1} }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
    0 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ .. } &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ .. } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ .. } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ .. } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n-1} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ .. } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n} &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ .. } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}%
};
\node[right=3em] at (A.east) (B) {%
   \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{m-1} }  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
    0 &  & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor{gray!10} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    1 & \cellcolor{gray!40} & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!75} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    . & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \cellcolor{gray!50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \cellcolor{gray!50} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n-1} & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \textit{n} &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{..} & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}%
};
\node[right=3em] at (B.east) (C) {%
   \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m } } & 
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{..}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \textit{ m-1 } } \\
    \cline{2-6}
     & \cellcolor{gray!100} & \cellcolor{gray!75} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \cellcolor{gray!50} } &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  \cellcolor{gray!25} } & \cellcolor{gray!10} \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}%
};
\draw[->,thick] (A.east) ++(2pt,0pt) -- (B.west);
\draw[->,thick] (B.east) ++(2pt,0pt) -- (C.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```